# joomla 3.7.2 version issues

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

In Joomla 3.7.2, the Joomla and k2 article shared on facebook only the links are shared but not the images, any solution?

Comment: Why so loud? Please read [ask].

Comment: Hi Picard, Now i am change my question.

Answer (score 0):

---

The solution is already available in Joomla, just disable the "**Gzip page compression**" by following the simple instructions.

Login to Joomla backend administrator Go to **System →Global configuration → Server → Gzip Page Compression → "No"** and Save.

---

Answer (score 0):

Any post must to have Featured Image in order to show it via Facebook share. Or get more controls with Facebook open graph via this extension https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/phoca-open-graph/